# VS 2015 & vNext/MVC 6 IntelliSense issues - Resharper

Tags: visual-studio

I am having an issue with Visual Studio 2015 RC and IntelliSense when running the MVC6 vNext project template.  The project builds and runs just fine and nuget restores packages if I manually remove them.  The issue is that VS 'shows' that it cannot resolve my using statements throughout the project, thus breaking intellisense.  Has anyone had this issue where it builds and runs fine but does not show the using statements as resolved?

[image: VS Shows refs as unresolved]

Comment: screenshot of the error?

Comment: No errors specifically, as mentioned the project builds and runs fine, it is the RED text shown in the image that is the problem, Using System... etc...

Comment: OK, figured it out.  Suspending resharper removed the red text, but still no intellisense.  Tried to update resharper via the resharper menu in VS, this failed.  Manually installed version 9.1.1 of resharper over version 9.0.0, this made everything happy again (full install removed previous version of resharper).

Answer (score 2):

OK, figured it out. Suspending resharper removed the red text, but still no intellisense. Tried to update resharper via the resharper menu in VS, this failed. Manually installed version 9.1.1 of resharper over version 9.0.0, this made everything happy again (full install removed previous version of resharper).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use ReSharper 2016.2 or above to support .net core.

You can use the early access version available from https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+2016.2+EAP

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue of `Resharper 9`. Don't use `Resharper 9` with `MVC 6`. It will suggest you the wrong path when you import CSS or JavaScript file to your page, as I said in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34616208/resharper-intellisense-suggests-wrong-path-in-mvc-6).

So, the solution is: update to `Resharper 10`. However, there are many problem remains when using `Resharper` with `MVC 6`.