# Resharper intellisense suggests wrong path in MVC 6

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, resharper, intellisense, asp.net-core-mvc

Here is my solution:

[image: MVC 6 Solution]

I want to import `site.css`. I know the correct path is: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />`.

But as you can see, Resharper is suggesting me a different path. Follow Resharper intellisense, the path would be: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/wwwroot/css/site.css" />`. This is a wrong path, and the file will not be imported.

So, my question is: how can I fix this in Resharper? How to let Reshaper know that it shouldn't include `wwwroot` in the path?

I'm using `Visual Studio 2015`, `Resharper 9.2`. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A bug has already been filed](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-451650) on their tracker and [as per one of the developer](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-451650#comment=27-1245232):

> R# 10.0.1 and 10.0.2 handles wwwroot setting correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After upgrade it to R# 10.0.2, it works well now :)